# is there any way that we can integrate asp.net with php.?

Tags: php, asp.net

I know that ASP.NET Application can run with PHP application on IIS through fastCGI, but is there any way to integrate both application, so that i can utilize codes from php and Asp.net working together.

during my research I found a third party tool known as Phalanger that converts the php code into MSIL and runs with .net application but the problem what i have is that it is in beta version and sessions_start() function is not running properly. Any other good ideas??? if so please let me know.

Comment: I don't see why you can't have PHP running on Apache and ASP.NET running on IIS on the same box unless there is something about IIS I don't understand.  I have Apache and JBoss running on the same box on the same port, different contexts, JBoss running on the webapp context and Apache running on the ROOT context.

Comment: I can run it. but that is not what i want, i want to integrate php app with asp.net. any chance of it???

Comment: Which part do you want to integrate. What will the integration do? I used to combine the different application pools of .net and classic asp. I made a "bridge" that communicated between the pools with Html `form` elements, posting to eachother

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate" exactly? This needs way more detail. What do you want to run where? Do you only want to share sessions, or more?

Comment: You can run a php website and an asp website with no problems on the same IIS box just install php and use php and asp extensions where appropriate.  If you want to have php and asp code in the same file, that is more complicated (and ridiculous), probably impossible and definitley a bad idea.  You need to explain in detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: i need to share sessions.. i want to integrate OScommerce(shopin cart app) site with our existing asp.net site having details of product on asp.net but cart system and registration on php side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking to have a single document which contains both the language types running side by side.

I do not believe it would be possible using your standard resources from php.net and Microsoft.
As you've mentioned, there may be tools to convert the code but the success may vary (I'm unable to advise of any myself).

In IIS you'd configure an Application Extensions against file extensions. For example .ASPX against aspnet_isapi.dll or .PHP against php5_isapi.dll.

You would need to have the same application extension in twice against two ISAPI extensions and IIS will not allow you to do this.

As for Apache, as it's text based it would obviously allow for setting this but will likely not work as desired.

Even if this was to work I would also consider it a bad idea as you'd be likely encounter other problems down the line.

I would suggest you look at an cart application built in ASP.NET rather than trying to merge two different languages together that are typically not built for this function.